# Decide if any suffix of a string is a prefix of another string

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, suffix-array

How can I check if any suffix of a string is a prefix of an another string, preferably in constant time, if I already built a suffix array of the first string?

Example:

string 1:

```
abc
```

string 2:

```
bcda
```

`bc` is a substring of first string, and a prefix of the second.

Comment: show some examples and what you tried to solve this problem

Comment: Right now, i'm checking every substring if it's a prefix, which is not very efficient, and I don't have a good idea how to do it better.

Comment: which language are you working on ?

Comment: In C#, but I just need some general algorithm.

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions ?

Comment: Maybe I could use a binary search and check only the suffixes starting with the first letter of the other string, but that's still not in constant time.